# Container DIV not expanding to include DIVs with absolute positioning

Tags: css, css-position

I imagine there is a simple solution, but it eludes me.  If you look at [this page](http://salliannputman.com/test.html) you will see that only the header has a grey background.  The grey background is set by the #container DIV which I would like to stretch down the entire height of the page:

```
#container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

At the moment it is only stretching over the header section of the page, and the content below is not contained within it.  I imagine that is because the main content in the #content DIV has absolute positioning, which I need in order to be able to do some animations on the positioning of this div (you can see this when you hover over the nav bar image):

```
#content {
    font-family: Lucida sans unicode !important;
    color: #CECBBB;
    text-align: justify;
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

From some research it would seem that DIVs with absolute positioning are not included in the height of parent DIVs, but I am not sure how to fix this.

I'd be grateful for some help.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to have `#content` absolutely positioned (as you state in your question) then the best way to get the background you desire is to either put the `background-color: #292929` on the `#content` itself (you will probably need to adjust some positioning and padding to eliminate any black).

However, if the animation is the submenu at the top that opens on hover, then I suggest setting both the menu and the content divs to `position: relative,` and instead of animating the `top` position of the `#content` (as your script appears to be doing), animate the `height` of the menu (have it zero as default and animate to something like 45px high [that's what firebug showed the height to be open]).

Comment: @Nick--it looks like you are getting there. I see background now, and you appear to be working on the hover. I think you will get it functioning as you expect.

Comment: Yes, I have sorted the background, but the submenu isn't working as I hoped using your method.  I would like to preserve a slideDown/Up and a fade, but can't work out how to do this.  You can see my question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464707/script-to-animate-height-of-div-is-changing-the-height-of-div-suddenly).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you're right. Elements with **absolute positioning** are not considered anymore in layout of their parent container. To understand it better, I recommend you read [CSS Positioning from A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/).

IMHO, you have many solutions:

1. Use floated layout, instead of absolute positioned layout
2. Hardcode the height of `container` element
3. Use JavaScript to always update the height of the `container` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
    color: #CECBBB;
    font-family: Lucida sans unicode !important;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

add a margin-top and remove the position absolute will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on Cecil's answer here.

One can position divs with margins instead, in order to make sure parent grows with child.

Se this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/944oahmy/10/

Where the following css is used

```
#parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 500px;
}
```