# Kendo gauge with three pointers -- Aligning 3 gauges on top of each other problems

Tags: asp.net, razor, kendo-ui, gauge

So I have tried copying countless other posts about aligning gauges and divs on top of each other using z-index and positioning but as of yet I still havent been able to accomplish it.
I currently have this(ive tested in IE and chrome with same results):

```
<div id="gauges">
    <div id="loggedInGauge">  //gauge creation code  </div>
    <div id="loggedOutGauge"> //gauge creation code </div>
    <div id="onBreakGauge">   //gauge creation code </div> 
</div>
<style>

             #gauges {
                position: relative;

            }
            #loggedInGauge, #loggedOutGauge, #onBreakGauge {

                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                bottom: 0px;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;    
            }

            #loggedOutGauge {

                z-index: 10;
            }
            #onBreakGauge {
                z-index: 20;
            }

</style>
```

Can anyone help to get the gauges on top of each other so that it looks like one gauge with three pointers?

Here is what the current output is: [Imgur link to current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNoZc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS definition to:

```
#loggedInGauge, #loggedOutGauge, #onBreakGauge {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;    
}
```

Kendo UI defines the position por each `gauge` as relative overwriting your definition. Adding the `! important` to it, we prevent this to happen.

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/wNsRY/

Comment: Thank you! Surely this should be in the Kendo documentation? It may be and I've just missed it, but it should be there. The only issue that has cropped up with using this is that the gauge container div has now messed up where it appears on the screen. [This](http://imgur.com/wxPNxNw) image shows what I mean. By the way the site looks so rubbish because I'm trying to get the charts sorted before I layout the rest of the page :)

Comment: Actually my proposed solution should be (and pretty sure it is) in CSS manuals since what I did is check the code generated and force what I want. The problem that you have now is due to the fact of being `position: absolute`, the container (`gauge` div) doesn't know about it's size :-( You might define a `height` in `gauge` CSS _forcing_ its size. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463686/1802671

Comment: From my point of view the _actual_ solutions would be support an array of pointers, something that is easily doable but depends on how many people would be interested on in for implementing it or not.